# Math.pow() in Java 8 and Java 13 returns different result

Tags: java, math, jvm

This following code returns different results on Java 8 and Java 11.

```
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        long x = 29218;
        long q = 4761432;
        double ret = Math.pow(1.0 + (double) x / q, 0.0005);
        System.out.println("val = " + String.format("%.24f", ret));
    }
}
```

Java 8:

```
val = 1.000003058823805400000000
```

Java 11: (The same result as Python, Rust)

```
val = 1.000003058823805100000000
```

The questions are these:

- Any documentation to describe this kind of behavior?
- How to implement Java 8's `Math.pow()` in Python?
- How to ensure strict consistency with older programs using the Java 8 library?

Comment: Is it a different *value* or is it `String.format()` behaving differently?

Comment: different value

Comment: How do you know it is a different value?

Comment: Are these java's both on the same machine?

Comment: One question, why does the last digit matter? For most applications the provided 16 significant decimal digits is more than enough. You might conceivably want more digits of accuracy, but in those cases you would want a different technique, say a library doing all calculations using long-doubles with  30+ decimal digits.

Comment: @Salixalba When you need to be strictly consistent with older programs.

Comment: When you need strictly consistent results, your program should have used `StrictMath.pow(…)` in the first place. Trying to get “strict consistency” with a particular implementation of the non-strict API makes no sense.

Comment: @Holger I do not write java programs. I need to copy the behavior to another language.

Comment: Why? There’s still no sense in this task.

Comment: @Holger In daily programming, one never meets this. But when you must copy the behavior of an old program or system, and all old data generated must be reproducible, You must implement it. So with some 8087 assembly, I've done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, the quick answer is `strictfp`. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp

In java8, the default behavior is using x87 FPU on x86 machines, which will use extended double(80bit) as intermediate values. So the result will not be guaranteed to be the same value on another platform.

In java11 or java13, the default behavior is using IEEE double(64bit) as intermediate values.

Since almost all modern languages guarantee stable results via IEEE-floats, this behavior is tricky to mimic in other languages or new java. Inline x87 FPU assembly might help.

Answer (score 11):

If we just use Double.toString() to print the answers then the two different results would be

```
1.0000030588238054
1.0000030588238051
```

The extra digits at the end are just a factor of the String.format(). We see the numbers only differ by the last significant decimal digit. Converting the two numbers to hexadecimal give

```
1.000033518c576
1.000033518c575
```

so the binary representations only differ by one unit in the last place (ulp).

Reading the spec for [Math.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) we find

"The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result."

The true value is close to 1.000003058823805246468 ([WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B0.006136389220721833%29%5E0.0005)) somewhere between the two answers, so both are within the spec.

All which has happened is that the library has had a slight change in algorithm, maybe to make it faster.

Comment: I could have skipped my work if you were even a bit faster. But anyway, two ways of explaining the same thing are not necessarily bad. Take my salute and +1 for being the faster answerer…

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not answered.

Answer (score 7):

Note that

```java
System.out.println("val = " + String.format("%.24f", ret));
```

is an unnecessary mix from `printf` style formatting, string concatenation, and `println`. You can use `printf` in the first place:

```java
System.out.printf("val = %.24f%n", ret);
```

However, there is no point in requesting 24 decimal digits, when the `double` precision does not even remotely provide that many digits. When you use

```java
System.out.println("val = " + ret);
```

instead, it will default to the actually available digits, which yields

```
val = 1.0000030588238054
```

for Java 8 and

```
val = 1.0000030588238051
```

for Java 11.

So the difference is only in the last digit. Or more precisely

```java
double d1 = 1.0000030588238051, d2 = 1.0000030588238054;
System.out.println((d2 - d1) == Math.ulp(d1));
```

prints `true`, so the distance between these two values is the smallest possible with `double`. There is no other `double` value in between them. The [specification of `pow` says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)):

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result.

Since the code above showed, that both results have a distance of one ulp, both results would be correct when the exact result lies between both results. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+%2B+29218%2F4761432%29%5E0.0005) says, the exact result starts with

```
1.000003058823805246…
```

So it lies between these two results. So both results are correct according to the specification.

For easier comparison:

```
1.0000030588238054         JDK  8
1.000003058823805246…      Wolfram Alpha
1.0000030588238051         JDK 11
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not answered.

Comment: Then, “your question” is not the question you have posted. You asked for “documentation to describe this kind of behavior” and you got it.

Comment: Google the keyword `strictfp` and that's the answer.